# Waiting for Writer.write to complete in Caml Async

Tags: asynchronous, ocaml

I have the following simple OCaml Async job which is supposed to write to a file and terminate the process.

```
Unix.openfile "foobar" ~mode:[`Creat;`Rdwr]
>>= fun fd ->
let wr = Writer.create fd in
Writer.write wr "this is a test";
Unix.close fd
>>= fun () ->
exit 0
```

However, it seems that `fd` gets closed before the write is performed (part of displayed sexp is "writer fd unexpectedly closed"). Is there a way to wait for write to complete before closing the file descriptor? Actually, I don't understand why `Writer.write` doesn't return a `Deferred.t` just as `Reader.read` does. Wouldn't it solve the issue?

My problem is actually a little more general. Basically, I have a periodic job that writes something to a file using `Clock.every'`. The program can exit at any time and close the file descriptors. How to make sure that all the writes are processed before the `fd` get closed?

If my stopping job is:

```
Unix.close fd
>>= fun () ->
exit 0
```

A scheduled write can very well happen between `Unix.close fd` and `exit 0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your particular case, you shouldn't close the file descriptor directly with the `Unix.close` function. The idea is that you actually moved the ownership of `fd` to the writer, so it is now the writer's responsibility to close the file descriptor. So, you need to use `Writer.close` that returns a unit deferred. This function, will wait until all pending writes are finished, and then close the file descriptor, e.g.,

```
Unix.openfile "foobar" ~mode:[`Creat;`Rdwr]
>>= fun fd ->
let wr = Writer.create fd in
Writer.write wr "this is a test";
Writer.close fd
>>= fun () ->
exit 0
```

Answering your more general question "Is there a way to wait for write to complete before closing the file descriptor?". Yes, `Writer.close` will wait. In the sence that it will return a deferred that will become determined after everything is written and fd is closed. You can also use a `force_close` parameter, that will force the closing operation leading to abrupt writes, if it considered a better option to the hanging program. E.g., you can give a program a reasonable amount of time to flush data, and then terminate with an error.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. However, what does it mean that I moved the ownership to the writer? Suppose I want to use fd again after the first write for something else, say a `lseek`to write at a different part of the file.  In that case, I'd have to wait for the first write but I don't want to close the file descriptor. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Well, then your program will be eventually broken, this is the same as with C streams library, and any other buffered IO, once you passed a descriptor to it, don't use the descriptor directly anymore, unless you really understand what's going on underneath the hood. This is not only a problem with the close call but with the ordinary writes, that will come out not in order with the buffered writes to the writer. So my suggestion is, either do not use the `Writer` interface at all or use the Writer interface everywhere. Don't try to stick somewhere in between.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to figure this out. I'll ask a new question if needed.