# Concurrent write with OCaml Async

Tags: asynchronous, ocaml

I'm reading data from the network and I'd like to write it to a file whenever I get them. The writes are concurrent and non sequential (think P2P file sharing). In C, I would get a file descriptor to the file(for the duration of the program) then use `lseek`, followed by `write` and eventually close the `fd`. These operations could be protected by a mutex in a multithreaded setting (especially, lseek and write should be atomic).

I don't really see how to get that behavior in Async. My initial idea is to have something like this.

```
 let write fd s pos = 
     let posl = Int64.of_int pos in
     Async_unix.Unix_syscalls.lseek fd ~mode:`Set posl
     >>| fun _ -> 
     let wr = Writer.create t.fd in
     let len = String.length s in
     Writer.write wr s ~pos:0 ~len
```

Then, the writes are scheduled asynchronously when data is received.

My solution isn't correct. For one thing, this `write` task need to be atomic but it is not the case, since two `lseek` can be executed before the first `Writer.write`. Even if I can schedule the `write` sequentially it wouldn't help since `Writer.write` doesn't return a `Deferred.t`. Any idea?

BTW, this is a follow-up to a previous answered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45148780/waiting-for-writer-write-to-complete-in-caml-async).

Comment: Ok, so you want multiple concurrent threads writing to the same file at different positions? I.e., each thread basically gets data and a position where to write?

Comment: Yes, this is the idea.

Comment: What you want is pwrite() instead of lseek + write. Not sure Async_unix has it but it's what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic approach would be to have a queue of workers, where each worker performs an atomic `seek/write`<sup>1</sup> operation. The invariant is that only one worker at a time is running. A more complicated strategy would employ a priority queue, where writes are ordered by some criterium that maximizes the throughput, e.g., writes to subsequent positions. You may also implement a sophisticated buffering strategy if you observe lots of small writes, then a good idea would be to coalesce them into larger chunks.

But let's start with a simple non-prioritized queue, implemented via `Async.Pipe.t`. For the positional write, we can't use the Writer interface, as it is designed for buffered sequential writes. So, we will use the `Unix.lseek` from `Async_unix.Std` and Bigstring.really_write`function. The really_write is a regular non-asynchronous function, so we need to lift it into the Async interface using the`Fd.syscall_in_thread` function, e.g.,

```
let really_pwrite fd offset bytes = 
  Unix.lseek fd offset ~mode:`Set >>= fun (_ : int64) ->
  Fd.syscall_in_thread fd (fun desc -> 
    Bigstring.really_write desc bytes)
```

Note: this function will write as many bytes as system decides, but no more than the length of `bytes`. So you might be interested in implementing a `really_pwrite` function that will write all bytes.

The overall scheme would include one master thread, that will own a file descriptor and accept write requests from multiple clients via an Async.Pipe. Suppose that each write request is a message of the follwing type:

```
 type chunk = {
    offset : int;
    bytes : Bigstring.t;
 }
```

Then your master thread will look like this:

```
let process_requests fd = 
  Async.Pipe.iter ~f:(fun {offset; bytes} -> 
    really_pwrite fd offset bytes)
```

Where the `really_pwrite` is a function that really writes all the bytes and handles all the errors. You may also use `Async.Pipe.iter'` function and presort and coalesce the writes before actually executing the `pwrite` syscall.

One more optimization note. Allocating a bigstring is a rather expensive operation, so you may consider to pre allocate one big bigstring and serve small chunks from it. This will create a limited resource, so your clients will wait until other clients will finish their writes and release their chunks. As a result, you will have a throttled system with a limited memory footprint.

---

<sup>1)</sup>Ideally we should use `pwrite` though Janestreet provides only `pwrite_assume_fd_is_nonblocking` function, that doesn't release OCaml runtime when a call to the system `pwrite` is done, and will actually block the whole system. So we need to use a combination of a seek and write. The latter will release the OCaml runtime so that the rest of the program can continue. (Also, given their definition of nonblocking fd, this function doesn't really make much sense, as only sockets and FIFO are considered non-blocking, and as far as I know, they do not support the seek operation. I will file an issue on their bug tracker.

Comment: I'm having an issue with the nonblocking flag in `Fd.syscall`. `syscall` fails with `Fd.set_nonblock_if_necessary called on fd that does not support nonblock`. I don't see how my fd can support non-block.  I open the file with `Unix.openfile name ~mode:['Creat;'Rdwr; 'Nonblock]`. Any idea?

Comment: 1) Is your file regular? 2) What OS are you using? 3) Which version of Async?

Comment: Also, a long shot, try to remove the `Nonblock` flag from the open flags. Maybe a library is trying to switch to the non-blocking mode a fd that is already in the non-blocking mode and fails on it.

Comment: Mac OS 10.12. Regular file. Async 0.9.0. `Fd.supports_nonblock fd` returns false right after `openfile`.

Comment: So I found in their source that a regular file is always considered as non-blocking, since <cite>No point in setting nonblocking for files.  Unix doesn't care.</cite> Though indeed, a regular file is already non-blocking, unlike socket or pipe, Unix will ignore the `O_NONBLOCK` flag, and will never terminate a write `EAGAIN`, but this doesn't really make it a blocking fd. Apparently, the nonblocking term is heavily overloaded and we have a poor choice of names, basically, if we will read `supports_nonblock` as `would_fail_on_block`, then everything will make sense. Updated the post.